# Schedule a cron job in nodejs loopback

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs

how to schedule the cron job in nodejs with loopback framework.

In service I defined the API from the API the it goes to module and did the action. But I dont know how to schedule it in the app.js file.

```
var http = require('http');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

I tried with this but its not running.

Comment: try [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) module it is highly used and much better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36904615/2680461

Comment: This cant work because I am using loopback framework. So I dont know how to trigger the cron job. var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage', 'lbServices', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCsv', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngDialog', 'checklist-model']). This is in the app.js file

Comment: are you saying that you want to schedule corn in angular, am not getting your point, please elaborate.

Comment: Am using angularjs with loopback framework and nodejs. In this I created a script in nodejs and how to schedule it in the app.js file. I tried with the nodejs schedule in app.js but the job wont run when  my application is started.

Comment: can you share you ```app.js``` code, have to see where did you went wrong while running the job.

Comment: This is my app.js file http://pastebin.com/cV38b2B0

Answer (score 4):

Just add a new file in server/boot not in app.js .

```
module.exports = function(app) {
 var http = require('http');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put your code on server/boot or client/boot i.e. *crons.js*

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

module.exports = (app) => {
     console.log("running job scheduler.."); 
     var job = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(){
         console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
     });
}
```

Sample code above will run the scheduler in every one minute. you might want to check the documentation of node-schedule [here](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#cron-style-scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

Node Schedule, which is the Cron-like schedule for Node, also provides an object literal syntax that you can use.

In your question, you note that you are using this:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

However, you could use something more like this:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 14, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 0}, function(){
    console.log('Time for tea!');
});
```

This is only a brief example, as I don't know the details of what you are trying to do, but you would need to create an API/remote method on the Loopback server where you could pass the input as JSON, such as:

```
{
    hour: 1,
    minute: 30,
    second: 0
}
```

Then, your app would call the exposed API that you just created. Hope this helps and let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback (server) app isn't the right place for this. You can use you model's outside the context of a server (eg. a simple node script) like this:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

More here: https://hackernoon.com/nodejs-javascript-cron-cron-jobs-cronjob-reactjs-scheduler-schedule-example-tutorial-25bcbe23bc6b